# conio setcolor(BLACK) not working

Tags: c, bgi, turbo-c

The method setcolor(BLACK) is not working on a WHITE background. If the background color is BLACK and setcolor(WHITE) then it displays the circle border correctly. This doesn't happen for any other color.

```
#include<graphics.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    int gd=DETECT,gm;
    initgraph(&gd,&gm,"C:\\TC\\BIN");
    setbkcolor(WHITE);
    setcolor(BLACK);
    circle(100,100,50);
    getch();
    closegraph();
}
```

Comment: This is old dos stuff, omg! Where did you set graphics mode? It seems uninitialized to me.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti ... graphics mode? well i found this piece of code online. i was just trying it out...other colors works just fine even if the graphics mode is left un initialized....

Comment: Do you mean it works ONLY when white on black? Oh i don't remember *that* days, maybe turbo c zeroed local variables (but I'd try to set it to vgalo - or whatever it was)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti *graphics mode?* gd=DETECT does that.

Comment: @user like an explicit call to detectgraph() -  or whatever it was? My memory about bgi is gone...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti what i meant was.... when the background is set to White and setcolor() to Black....there is no output...maybe because the setcolor() is default to WHITE and the output is also drawn in White.... but that assumption was wrong cuz when i set the setcolor() to any other color, the output is visible with that specified color.

Comment: It's more than 20 years I used that stuff last time but I think it should work and I'd exclude a bug...any issue with dos emulation?

Comment: no, no issues......any other color for me is fine...so its not a problem anymore